# Converting Wiki to DTP format

Tags: print-design

I am looking for a way to **convert Wiki to a DTP format** - what is the most efficient (fast but preserving all of the document elements) way to do that? The "DTP format" can be any format used in the industry but it should allow me to edit the document after processing the Wiki.

My publication may include many elements of wiki syntax, i.e. tables, images, links, code blocks, maybe even math equations.

I use wikidot.com but Wiki format is not an issue here, it can be easily converted to any other wiki syntax.

**If this is not the right place to ask such questions, point me to the right forum please.**

Comment: Easiest is probably to open each page in a browser and FILE > PRINT > SAVE AS PDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DA01's suggestion in his comment would handle some of what you need. If you have Acrobat installed, you should have an active plug-in in IE and/or Firefox that will allow you to save the website as a PDF. At that point you could use [PDF2ID](http://www.recosoft.com/products/pdf2id) to convert the PDF to an InDesign document. PDF2ID does an amazing job of building clean InDesign documents, complete with styles that make sense and formatting intact.

An alternative approach, not necessarily elegant, is to use a utility such as [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) to download part or all of the site. Then it's a matter of copy/paste into your DTP application from the actual pages, but you'll be certain not to lose any links or high-resolution version of images that are displayed as thumbnails in the Wiki. This could also work in conjunction with the first approach.

What you're describing isn't a common workflow, so you'll likely have to experiment a bit, but my experience tells me that a combination of PDF and HTTrack will likely get you the product you're looking for. I used HTTrack recently on a blog-to-book project (>600 printed pages in three volumes), so I can attest to that as a workable solution where you want to impose your own styling rather than simply replicate the wiki on paper.